# How to send messages from electron to another process (other native windows app)

Tags: windows, electron

I am having a native windows app that sends messages to the electron app via WM_COPYDATA. In electron I use hookWindowMessage to receive the message.

Is it possible to send messages back to the process, if I know the hwnd?

How can I respond to the message? Is there a method I can use?

Cheers,
Till

Answer (score 0):

you use TCP/UDP socket for process communication. that will be more reliable.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!
Unfortunately I must use WM_COPYDATA, as this is how it is implemented in the other native windows app. Is it possible to use WM_COPYDATA directly from electron?